# Bootstrap button classes duplicate when you inspect, How can i reslove this issue?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap button where i am using `btn btn-default` but when i inspect using chrome its showing multiple classes on this button, I could not catch the problem why it is happening. Any help will be appreciated.

main.html

```
</accordion-group> <accordion-group is-open="challengeAccordion.isOpen"
    disable-control-point="CHALLENGES_VIEW"
    context-val-id="processDTO.erhUtilKeyList"
    ng-show="editMode && !CHALLENGES_VIEW"
    disable-Page-Elements="{{challengesAccordion}}"
    disablelevel="challenges">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group clearfix">
            <button class="btn btn-default pull-right mousedwncall"
                require-control-point="CHALLENGES_ADD"
                context-val-id="processDTO.erhUtilKeyList"
                ng-click="addProcessChallenge()">Add Challenge</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

main.js

```
angular.module('disablePageElements', []).directive('disablePageElements', function ($compile, $rootScope, $timeout) {
    'use strict';
       var disableButtons = function(inputs){          
                    angular.forEach(inputs, function(el){
                           el = angular.element(el);
                           var className = angular.element(el).attr('class');
                           if(angular.isUndefined(className) || !angular.isUndefined(className) && className.indexOf('ignoreDisable') === -1){
                                  var prevVal = el.attr('ng-disabled');
                                  prevVal = prevVal? prevVal +  ' || true': 'true';                           
                                  el.attr('ng-disabled', prevVal);

                                  var classPrevVal = el.attr('class');
                                  if(classPrevVal.indexOf('disableSaveCls') === -1){
                                      classPrevVal = classPrevVal ? classPrevVal +  ' btn btn-primary disableSaveCls': ' btn btn-primary disableSaveCls';
                                  }
                                  el.attr('class', classPrevVal);

                                  $compile(el)(scope);
                           }                                 
                    });
                };
});
```

chromeInspectElement Code

```
<button class="btn btn-default pull-right mousedwncall btn btn-primary disableSaveCls ng-scope" require-control-point="CHALLENGES_ADD" context-val-id="processDTO.erhUtilKeyList" ng-click="addProcessChallenge()" ng-disabled="true || true || true || true" disabled="disabled">Add Challenge</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably a directive which add additionnal style.

try this

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group clearfix">
        <button class="btn btn-default pull-right"
            ng-click="addProcessChallenge()">Add Challenge</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited my question you are right there is directive disablePageElements that is causing issue now i dont know how to make the fix , please see directive and let me know where i can fix it.

Comment: Just remove the style.
classPrevVal = classPrevVal ? classPrevVal +  ' disableSaveCls': ' btn btn-primary disableSaveCls';

Comment: do you think it will effect other buttons ?

Comment: so i need to remove if condition completely for styling

Answer (score 0):

There's probably other external CSS files adding style to your button.

For example, ng-scope is part of AngularJS

Comment: But why its happening to this particular button i have tons of button with same implementation.